# NUnit C# syntax for exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, nunit

I need to write tests for some collection of enum values.
When using part of them I expect an exception and my test need to handle that.

I can write test method with `[ExpectedException]` and param of my enum value.
I can write method which uses foreach to enumerate enum values which are expected to raise an exception. But in this case i think first exception will be raised and rest enum values wont be checked.

How to correctly enumerate enum values and check exception with single or 2 maybe methods ?

I just dont want to have one new method for each enum value i need to check.

Answer (score 4):

You can use NUnits parametrized tests with the `TestCase` attribute.

This will allow you to write two tests: One for the enum values that should throw an exception and one for the enum values that shouldn't throw an exception.

```
[Test]
[TestCase(MyEnum.ExceptionValue1)]
[TestCase(MyEnum.ExceptionValue2)]
[TestCase(MyEnum.ExceptionValue3)]
public void MethodShouldThrowForInvalidValues(MyEnum value)
{
    var sut = new MyClass();

    Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => sut.MyMethod(value));
}

[Test]
[TestCase(MyEnum.ValidValue1)]
[TestCase(MyEnum.ValidValue2)]
[TestCase(MyEnum.ValidValue3)]
public void MethodShouldNotThrowForValidValues(MyEnum value)
{
    var sut = new MyClass();

    sut.MyMethod(value);

    Assert.True(true);
}
```

---

An alternate way is to use a type or property that returns all enum values for which the method should throw an exception:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource("InvalidEnumValues")]
public void MethodShouldThrowForInvalidValues(MyEnum value)
{
    var sut = new MyClass();

    Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => sut.MyMethod(value));
}


public IEnumerable<MyEnum> InvalidEnumValues
{
    get
    {
        // here you can put a foreach if you like
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer Assert.Throws<MyException>() over [ExpectedException)typeof(MyExxception))]

Comment: Thank you. Any possibility to use foreach instead of testcase ? I just have big enum, about 45 values and type "long" used for values

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan: I didn't know that exists in NUnit, as I am an xUnit user. Changed accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @Alexander - TestCase attribute is a god way for Data Driven Tests. Foreach makes the code uglier IMHO.

Comment: @Alexander: This is cleaner than a foreach. What you can do is implement a type that returns the enumeration values and use the `TestCaseSourceAttribute` instead of the `TestCaseAttribute`. Like that you will not clutter the test class with these 45 lines of `TestCase` attributes definitions.

Comment: Right... but i have a lot of enum values, and want be sure i will add new value to enum, this test will let me know if i need to fix smth about exception

Comment: Thank you very much. I think 2nd example is really what i need.

Comment: @Alexander, please mark this as an answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your test code might look like this. Consider spliting `TestMethod` into two method, so that you don't need to pass `bool` flag

```
[TestFixture]
class Test
{

    [TestCase(MyEnum.Foo, false)]
    [TestCase(MyEnum.Bar, true)]
    public void TestMethod(MyEnum myEnum, bool shouldExceptionBeThrown)
    {
        if (shouldExceptionBeThrown)
            Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => MethodUnderTest(myEnum));
        else
            MethodUnderTest(myEnum);
    }

    public void MethodUnderTest(MyEnum myEnum)
    {
        if(myEnum == MyEnum.Bar)
            throw new Exception();
    }
}

internal enum MyEnum
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how TestCaseSource can help for large data driven tests:

Here is a way to define the test data source -

```
private class InputData
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _keywords;
    public InputData()
    {
        _keywords = new Dictionary<string, string>
                       {
                           {"abc", "test case 1"},
                           {"xyz", "test case 2"},
                       };
    }
}
```

And it's usage:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(InputData), "_keywords")]
public void MethodShouldNotThrowForValidValues(KeyValuePair<string, string> value)
{
    var sut = new MyClass();

    var val = sut.MyMethod(value);

    Assert.True(val);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that throw an exception at runtime because of unmatching types? `KeyValuePair<string, string>` <--> `MyEnum`

Comment: Damn copy paste.. Thanks Daniel

Comment: What is the reason to verify `Assert.True(true)`? :)